# Can 'rails g controller' generate restful routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way, using rails generators, to create a controller with RESTful routes?

Generating a controller and specifying the action name creates a controller and adds a route to `config/routes.rb`, but `create` is a `get`:

```
$ rails g controller foos new create
  create  app/controllers/foos_controller.rb
   route  get "foos/create"
   ...
```

I'd prefer to see `route post "foos"`, but don't see anything useful in `rails g controller --help`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `rails generate scaffold_controller Foos`

Comment: closer, but I was hoping to generate controller + routes only (no models or assets)

Comment: Then you should use rails generate scaffold_controller Foos ..that will not generate models and assets

Comment: use rails generate -h to see all the love the rails generator give you  :)

Comment: I did that, but didn't get any routes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command

```
rails generate controller Posts --skip-assets --skip-template-engine
```

the response will be likle this
create  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
invoke  test_unit
create    test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb