# Auto-generate routes for scaffolded controller in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, scaffolding

I'm trying to get a quick-and-dirty Ajax UI going for an app that already has its data model well in hand - it's basically been managed via `rails console` so far.  Anyway, I thought I would start by auto-generating the missing controller logic that you would get from a `rails g scaffold`, only instead with `rails g scaffold_controller` for an existing controller.

It created the controller, and the views, and the assets.. but it didn't touch the routes at all!  It didn't even try, didn't say "warning: routes.rb has been modified, not changing" or anything like that, and there's no mention of routes at all in the help output of `rails g scaffold_controller`.

So how do I say "Just give me the normal routes you would have given me if I started from scratch, please!"?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look on this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978447/can-rails-g-controller-generate-restful-routes

Comment: Thanks, @BenjaminBenoudis... that's where I started, by doing what the accepted answer there says, only it didn't work. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question:

Please, open the config/routes.rb file, and inside the block (routes.draw) add the resources method with the table name (plural of model) as param. Like this:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :products
  ... # rest of code
end
```

That define the routes for RESTful actions over products. You can read more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

At the console you can run: `rake routes` to see the available routes at your app.

Comment: Thank you.  I did figure that out, there was certainly less to it than I expected. Guess I'm stuck in old Rails 2 days. But I'm still wondering why scaffold adds the routes but scaffold_controller doesn't..

Comment: Because the routes are generated by the ResourceGenerator and ScaffoldGenerator inherits from ResourceGenerator, and the ScaffoldControllerGenerator inherits from NamedBased. More [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb#L5), [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/resource/resource_generator.rb#L17), and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/scaffold_controller_generator.rb#L5)

Answer (score 1):

Although this is asking about Rails 4 for long time ago, but with Rails 5, `rails g scaffold_controller` still won't auto-generate route, I did it with below monkey patch:

```
require 'rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/scaffold_controller_generator'

patcher = Module.new do
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    hook_for :resource_route, required: true
  end
end

Rails::Generators::ScaffoldControllerGenerator.send :include, patcher
```